# What is the fastest way to read data from a DbDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, database

In the following code, command is a DbCommand that has already been set up:

```
using( var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader() /*The actual execution of the query takes relatively little time.*/ ) {
                while( dataReader.Read() ) {
                    // These are what take all of the time. Replacing them all with reader.GetValues( myArray ) has no impact.
                    val0 = dataReader.GetValue( 0 );
                    val1 = dataReader.GetValue( 1 );
                    val2 = dataReader.GetValue( 2 );
                }
            }
```

The bulk of the time for the query I am currently working with is spent doing the GetValue calls. Is it making a round trip to the database for each GetValue call? It seems like it is, and this seems very inefficient. As the code notes, attempting to do it in one shot using GetValues() does not make a difference. Is there a way to get the entire row in one shot? Better yet, is there a way to get the entire result set in one shot?

Thanks.

Comment: Without writing your implementation, IDataReader and/or DbDataReader and "GetStrongScalarType( ordinalNumber ) is the faster.  GetString, GetInt32, etc. and 0, 1, 2 or ordinal.  At the end of the data, filling a DataTable or a DataSet or most ORM's are using IDataReader and/or DbDataReader, and using ordinal number.  ORM can use ("byStringColumnName"), but they usually (one time) map those to ordinals and cache it for repeat calls.  Example ORM : https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Driver/NHybridDataReader.cs

Comment: Don't use "GetValue".  Use the concrete GetString, GetInt32, etc, etc for best performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;" +
          "SELECT EmployeeID, LastName FROM dbo.Employees",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0),
                reader.GetName(1));

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
            reader.NextResult();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't any faster than the code I posted in the original question (it's roughly the same), but I think it's the fastest of the answers. At least we know now that there isn't some way-faster method that I was missing.

Answer (score 43):

I did some benchmarking myself with various approaches:

```
public DataTable Read_using_DataTable_Load(string query)
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        var table = new DataTable();
        using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            table.Load(r);
        return table;
    }
}

public DataTable Read_using_DataSet_Fill<S>(string query) where S : IDbDataAdapter, IDisposable, new()
{
    using (var da = new S())
    {
        using (da.SelectCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<S> Read_using_yield_selector<S>(string query, Func<IDataRecord, S> selector)
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            while (r.Read())
                yield return selector(r);
    }
}

public S[] Read_using_selector_ToArray<S>(string query, Func<IDataRecord, S> selector)
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            return ((DbDataReader)r).Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(selector).ToArray();
    }
}

public List<S> Read_using_selector_into_list<S>(string query, Func<IDataRecord, S> selector)
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection.Open(); 
        using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var items = new List<S>();
            while (r.Read())
                items.Add(selector(r));
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

1 and 2 returns `DataTable` while the rest strongly typed result set, so its exactly not apples to apples, but I while time them accordingly.

Just the essentials:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Read_using_DataTable_Load(query); // ~8900 - 9200ms

    Read_using_DataTable_Load(query).Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(selector).ToArray(); // ~9000 - 9400ms

    Read_using_DataSet_Fill<MySqlDataAdapter>(query); // ~1750 - 2000ms

    Read_using_DataSet_Fill<MySqlDataAdapter>(query).Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(selector).ToArray(); // ~1850 - 2000ms

    Read_using_yield_selector(query, selector).ToArray(); // ~1550 - 1750ms

    Read_using_selector_ToArray(query, selector); // ~1550 - 1700ms

    Read_using_selector_into_list(query, selector); // ~1550 - 1650ms
}

sw.Stop();
MessageBox.Show(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

The query returned about 1200 rows and 5 fields (run for 100 times). Apart from `Read_using_Table_Load` all performed well.

Of all I prefer `Read_using_yield_selector` which returns data lazily, as enumerated. This is great for memory if you only need to enumerate it. To have a copy of the collection in memory, you're better off with `Read_using_selector_ToArray` or `Read_using_selector_into_list` as you please.

Comment: +1 - Interesting, especially the comparison between `DataTable.Load()` and `IDataAdapter.Fill()`. I would have thought that the data adapter was the same or slower than loading directly to a `DataTable`, but it looks like it is 4-5x faster? Any idea why?

Comment: @TimMedora no idea, but I confirmed it trying with `SQLite Connector` as well which yielded just the same result which I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14807940/661933). Its so odd nevertheless.

Comment: @TimMedora: You need to surround the `DataTable.Load()` with `.BeginLoadData()` and `.EndLoadData()` to achieve the same speed as with the `DataSet`.

Comment: This answer contains useful information, but doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: @WilliamGross I believe I did. It happens a lot of times on SO where OP will have one question in the title and another one in the body (description). Though related, they wont be exactly the same often. I think I tried to answer "fastest way to read", and also "how to load it at once" written in the question body. But I take your criticism and will answer *more* appropriately later! :)

Comment: hi all, anyone can explain how to pass "Func<IDataRecord, S>" parameter in above Read5<S>(string query, Func<IDataRecord, S> selector).

Comment: @WinodPatel you would do something like: `var users = Read5("select * from User", r => new User { Id = r[0], Name = r[1] })`. Hope it's clear.

Comment: Yes nawfal, exactly i want it.
Thank u so much

Answer (score 4):

I would use something like [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) to load it into a basic type model; this is a micro-ORM, so you get the benefits of meta-programming (efficiently pre-generated IL etc) - without the overhead of things like EF or DataTable.

Comment: I don't think this would help with his specific question about data readers. Dapper itself uses DbDataReader.GetValue under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DbDataAdapter` to get all the results and store them in a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Dim adapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(DT)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Untyped DataSet. That is fastest, as far as I know.

Comment: Why are you considering it the "fastest?" You didn't supply any reasoning behind this answer.